# why getId doesn't work

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

i looking for id of linearlayout child but when call getid it's return -1

here is my code.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.schedul1);
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
        int id=layout.getChildAt(i).getId();
```

i trace and found that child variable not null but getId return -1.
why?
any suggestion for get id of child of linearlayout view.

Comment: Well have you set the id to the layouts? -1 is the default value

Comment: #Sam Dozor' answer is a good one. If  you like, post your XML to help you with the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're setting the ID of each view in your layout XML, or when you programmatically create the `View`, it will return the default (-1).

> Views **may** have an integer id associated with them. These ids are typically assigned in the layout XML files, and are used to find specific views within the view tree.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

The javadocs for `getId()` in the Android source code also clearly state this behavior:

> a positive integer used to identify the view or NO_ID if the view has no ID

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId()

And following through, `NO_ID` is equal to -1:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#NO_ID

Comment: child is TextView. how can i change text of child.

Comment: `((TextView)layout.getChildAt(i)).setText("some text")`